# Developing WordPress plugin in PhpStorm: "Path not found" - "Include expression is not resolved"

Tags: php, wordpress, phpstorm

In my main (index.php) plugin file I have declared the following constant:

```
define( 'MYPREFIX_PLUGIN_PATH', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) ); // includes trailing slash
```

In the same file, I use it like:

```
$container = require HATD_PLUGIN_PATH . 'Container/bootstrap.php';
```

PhpStorm 2019.1 complains with:

> Path 'MYPREFIX_PLUGIN_PATHContainer/bootstrap.php' not found
>
> *Inspection info*: Include expression is not resolved.

*The code works,* and I realize that I can dial these warnings down or turn them off, but ideally I could leave it on so that paths are evaluated/checked.

Has anyone found a fix for this annoyance?

Comment: I say just disable that inspection (Alt+Enter on it, arrow right on appropriate entry. Direct includes are not that popular these days (when you can use class autoloading) .. and there are nuances ... so devs do to give much priority to such tickets (my personal observation).

Comment: I see your point, but in this particular case, I am 'require'ing the file which boots up the psr-4 autoloader. But besides that, I am using generator classes which 'include' php (mostly html) templates. Should my templates be inside classes so that they are also autoloaded? Is there a best practice for this? Thanks!

Comment: I'm talking about from IDE side of things only (the appropriate inspection). Code works, so keep using it if it's OK. Here are the tickets (all of them): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI?q=unresolved%20include You can check which one is suits the most for your case. The problem for IDE that I see is that you use extra function `plugin_dir_path()` to have the constant value. It can be just too complex (IDE may skip it) to resolve such value.

Comment: But if you need include/require resolving: try using only standard stuff (`__DIR__`, `basename()` and stuff like that).

Comment: As for including templates: I'm not doing any serious WordPress coding (just basic things) so do not take this too "seriously".. but there I either use relative path to included file or may use some special function that does the job (so whole include logic is "hidden" from the main code).